# Decorator seems to be ignored in executable after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, dependencies, pytest, pyinstaller, executable

I have a file main.py which calls "pytest.main()"

I have a file "pytest.ini" which contains the "testpaths" = "my_test_file.py" and a marker for dependency

"my_test_file.py" looks kind of like this:

```
import pytest

class TestClass(object):
    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_a(self):
        assert False

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_a"])
    def test_b(self):
        pass
```

When I run main.py, I get expected behavior, 1 test failed, 1 test skipped. All good.

Now I use "pyinstaller" to create an executable from my file main.py. When I run the main.exe, I get 1 test failed 1 test passed as an output. test_b seems to ignore the decorator and does NOT skip. I use the following pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

What am I doing wrong that invokes python to ignore my decorator in the executable?

Also best practice suggestions will be greatly appreciated here.

Ultimate goal: A pytest executable single file, that when executed, runs a bunch of tests. If the very first test (connectivity test) fails, all other tests should be skipped. Works in my local environment but not after making an executable.

If you want to reproduce the problem, I am using the following versions:

```
python 3.7.5

pytest==6.1.0
pytest-dependency==0.5.1
pyinstaller==4.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2020.9
```

Comment: in test_b "self " is missing

Comment: @woblob was a typo in the question. Thanks for pointing it out